# Sending and receiving ArrayList with PubNub in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I publish an ArrayList as a message in PubNub:

```
ArrayList<Item> item_list = new ArrayList<Item>();
pubnub.publish().channel(my_channel).message(item_list);
```

How can I collect it and store it in another ArrayList when I receive it?

Comment: Do you mean "receive by PubNub subscribe" when you say receive it? If so, you should get the ArrayList in the subscribe, then store it when you receive it :) If that is not the case, then maybe you can provide some details, like an output of the data when you receive it? What format is it in?